# Identifying "Aria-Selected" State - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo-UI's Drag and Drop Tree View for an application I'm working on.

I'm looking to append some text to the selected list-item.

I can not find anything in the documentation and am having a hard time selecting the appropriate item.

This is the Kendo-UI code:

```
 <script>
            $("#treeview-left").kendoTreeView({
                dragAndDrop: true,
                dataSource: [
                    { text: "Furniture", expanded: true, items: [
                        { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
                        { text: "Sofas" },
                        { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
                    ] },
                    { text: "Decor", items: [
                        { text: "Bed Linen" },
                        { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
                        { text: "Carpets" }
                    ] }
                ]
            });

            $("#treeview-right").kendoTreeView({
                dragAndDrop: true,
                dataSource: [
                    { text: "Storage", expanded: true, items: [
                        { text: "Wall Shelving" },
                        { text: "Floor Shelving" },
                        { text: "Kids Storage" }
                    ]
                    },
                    { text: "Lights", items: [
                        { text: "Ceiling" },
                        { text: "Table" },
                        { text: "Floor" }
                    ]
                    }
                ]
            });
        </script>
```

This is a snippet of the generated code (notice the "aria-select='true'" , this is because I've selected the element, now I want to append text to this element):

```
<li role="treeitem" class="k-item" data-uid="82bceebe-f6a8-4d44-80ec-76f4b3db5041" aria-selected="true" id="treeview-left_tv_active">
<div class="k-top">
   <span class="k-icon k-plus" role="presentation"></span>
   <span class="k-in k-state-selected">Alberta</span>
</div>
<ul class="k-group" style="display:none" role="group">.....</ul>
</li>
```

This is my code at this point, I've tried a few other things, but have reverted back to this, which I know is incorrect:

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        $(".k-treeview li:first").click(function () {
            $(this).append("test");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aria attributes are for accessibility and not really meant to be used for other purposes.

You can use the [`select` event](http://docs.kendoui.com/kendo-ui/api/web/treeview#events-select) and access the selected element in `e.node`:

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: ds,
    select: function(e) {
        var model = this.dataItem(e.node);
        model.set("text", model.get("text") + "test");
    }
})
```

You can play with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/H85ac/4/).

If you want to get the selected node at other times, use the [`select` method](http://docs.kendoui.com/kendo-ui/api/web/treeview#methods-select).